# Argument of type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ type: string; } & void'

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-typings, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

**Error that i am facing:**
Argument of type '{ type: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ type: string; } & void'.
I am using redux thunk as middle ware it was working fine for 6 months now wehn i tried to reinstall it, it is giving me this error. can someone look into this?

```
 dispatch(getSummaryListingAction(GetSummaryListingsSuccess()));
 dispatch(getSummaryListingAction(GetSummaryListingsError(e.message)));
 dispatch(getSummaryListingAction(GetSummaryListingsError(e.message)));
 dispatch(getSummaryListingAction(GetSummaryListingsError(e.message)));
```

**Code**

```
import { LossReportAxios } from "../../../services/axios";
import { getSummaryListingAction } from "../../slices/lossReportingSlice";
import { AppDispatch } from "../../store";
import { summaryListingActionTypes } from "../summaryListing/summaryListingActionTypes";

const GetSummaryListingsStart = () => ({
    type: summaryListingActionTypes.GET_SUMMARYLISTING_START
});

const GetSummaryListingsSuccess = () => ({
    type: summaryListingActionTypes.GET_SUMMARYLISTING_SUCCESS,
});

const GetSummaryListingsError = (payload: any) => ({
    type: summaryListingActionTypes.GET_SUMMARYLISTING_ERROR,
    payload: payload
});

export const GetSummaryListings = (token: string,searchObjParams:any,searchBy:string,gridparams:any,navigate:any) => {
    return (dispatch: AppDispatch) => {
        dispatch(getSummaryListingAction(GetSummaryListingsStart()));
        
        if(searchBy === "CLIENT"){
            
            LossReportAxios
            .post(
                "/SummaryListingLossesByDepartmentForClientId",
                searchObjParams,
                {
                  headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                  },
                }
              ).then(function (res:any) {
                  var totalRows = -1;
                  if (res.data !== null && res.data !== undefined) {
                        if (res.data.length < 10) {
                            totalRows = gridparams.request.startRow + res.data.length;
                        }
                        gridparams.successCallback(res.data, totalRows);
                        dispatch(getSummaryListingAction(GetSummaryListingsSuccess()));
                    } else {
                        gridparams.successCallback([], totalRows);
                    }
                }).catch((e:any) => {
                    dispatch(getSummaryListingAction(GetSummaryListingsError(e.message)));
                });

        } else {
            LossReportAxios
            .post(
                "/SummaryListingLossesByDepartmentForPolicyId",
                searchObjParams,
                {
                  headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                  },
                }
              ).then(function (res:any) {
                var totalRows = -1;
                if (res.data) {
                    if (res.data.length < 50) {
                        totalRows = gridparams.request.startRow + res.data.length;
                    }
                    gridparams.successCallback(res.data, totalRows);
                    dispatch(getSummaryListingAction(GetSummaryListingsSuccess()));
                } else {
                    gridparams.successCallback([], totalRows);
                }
                }).catch((e:any) => {
                    dispatch(getSummaryListingAction(GetSummaryListingsError(e.message)));
                });
        }

    }
}
```

**redux configuration**

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { persistedReducer } from './RootReducer';
import logger from "redux-logger";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer
})
export const storeWithLogger = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware:(gDM) => gDM({
    serializableCheck:false
  }).concat(logger,thunk)
})
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

Comment: Generally you are aware that you are writing a very outdated style of Redux that is 3-4 times the amount of code of modern (post-2019) Redux, and even if you wanted to stay with legacy Redux, you could at least use `createAction` for your action creators?
See https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today

Comment: You are right @phry. but the thing is updating it now would be a very big change. But yes! maybe in the future I might change it. Thank you for taking time to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
It seems wierd but the solution is as follows:

```
import type { PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
getCommonState: (state = initialState, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {}
```

perviously I was using action:any

Answer (score 0):

For a test, leave out that `thunk` middleware in `concat` - the Redux thunk middleware is already part of `getDefaultMiddlware`.

```js
export const storeWithLogger = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware:(gDM) => gDM({
    serializableCheck:false
  }).concat(logger)
})
```

If that doesn't help: Can you attach the exact type you get when hovering your `AppDispatch` type?

Comment: unfortunately removing thunk had no effect. here is the appdispatch hover data:
type AppDispatch = ThunkDispatch<EmptyObject & {
    auth: Partial<AuthState>;
    common: Partial<CommonState>;
    lossreporting: Partial<DepartmentState>;
    genbill: GenbillState;
} & PersistPartial, undefined, AnyAction> & Dispatch<...>